# SQL - Sorting within an OVER clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm able to perform the following operation in SQL:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.SomeField2 ASC) AS r, c.cID
FROM 
 (
    SELECT c.SomeField1, c.SomeField2, c.SomeField3, t.SomeField1Text, p.SomeField2Text
    FROM MyTable c
    JOIN #TempTable1 t ON c.SomeField1 = t.SomeField1
    JOIN #TempTable2 p ON c.SomeField2 = p.SomeField2
) c
```

However, when I try sorting on a column from one of my temp tables like so…

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.SomeField2Text ASC) AS r, c.cID
FROM 
 (
    SELECT c.SomeField1, c.SomeField2, c.SomeField3, t.SomeField1Text, p.SomeField2Text
    FROM MyTable c
    JOIN #TempTable1 t ON c.SomeField1 = t.SomeField1
    JOIN #TempTable2 p ON c.SomeField2 = p.SomeField2
) c
```

… I get the following error:

```
The multi-part identifier "p.SomeFieldText2" could not be bound.
```

Do you know why I’m getting this error? I'm confused, since that column is in my `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I've edited the type-o in my question.  I still have the same problem.

Comment: have you tried `ORDER BY c.SomeField2Text ASC`?

Comment: Thanks @user2315555 , I just tried that after seeing Almazini's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider your subquery like a table with alias C.

That is why you need to order by c.SomeField2 column

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.SomeFieldText ASC) AS r, c.cID
FROM 
 (
    SELECT c.SomeField1, c.SomeField2, c.SomeField3, t.SomeField1Text, p.SomeField2Text, p.SomeField2
    FROM MyTable c
    JOIN #TempTable1 t ON c.SomeField1 = t.SomeField1
    JOIN #TempTable2 p ON c.SomeField2 = p.SomeField2
) c
```

Comment: So how do I sort on SomeField2Text?  I don't want to sort on SomeField2, because that is really just an ID.  I want to sort on the corresponding text value.

Comment: Got it... I can just use c.SomeField2Text, since c is my subquery table name. Thanks (I've edited the code in your answer, but your explanation made sense)

Answer (score 1):

The field you are querying is called `SomeField2Text`, not `SomeFieldText2`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.SomeField2Text ASC) AS r, c.cID
FROM 
 (
    SELECT c.SomeField1, c.SomeField2, c.SomeField3, t.SomeField1Text, p.SomeField2Text
    FROM MyTable c
    JOIN #TempTable1 t ON c.SomeField1 = t.SomeField1
    JOIN #TempTable2 p ON c.SomeField2 = p.SomeField2
) c
```

Comment: I've edited the type-o in my question.  I still have the same problem.